# Wrangling memory for a highly iterative c++ program

Tags: c++, memory-management, for-loop

tl:dr I am needing a way to better manage memory in C++ while retaining large datasets.

I am currently creating a program that outputs a database that I need for a later project, and I am struggling with memory control. I have the program written to a functional level that outputs the dataset that I am needing on a small scale, but to ramp up the size to where I need it and keep it realistic, I need to increase the number of iterations.  Problem is when I do that I end up running out of memory on my computer (4gb) and it has to start pagefiling, which slows the processing considerably.

The basic outline is that I am creating stores, then creating a year's worth of transactional data for said store.  When the store is created, a list of numbers is generated that represents the daily sales goals for the transactions, then transactions are randomly generated until that number is reached.  This method gives some nicely organic results that I am quite happy with.  Unfortunately all of those transactions have to be stored in memory until they are output to my file.

When the transactions are created they are temporarily stored in a vector, which I execute .clear() on after I store a copy of the vector in my permanent storage location.

I have started to try to move to unique_ptr's for my temporary storage, but I am unsure if they are even being deleted properly upon returning from the functions that are generating my data.

the code is something like this (I cut some superfluous code that wasn't pertinent to the question at hand)

```
void store::populateTransactions() {
    vector<transaction> tempVec;
    int iterate=0, month=0;
    double dayTotal=0;
    double dayCost=0;
    int day=0;
for(int i=0; i<365; i++) {
    if(i==dsf[month]) {
        month++;
        day=0;
    }
    while(dayTotal<dailySalesTargets[i]) {
        tempVec.push_back(transaction(2013, month+1, day+1, 1.25, 1.1));
        dayTotal+=tempVec[iterate].returnTotal();
        dayCost+=tempVec[iterate].returnCost();
        iterate++;
    }
        day++;

        dailyTransactions.push_back(tempVec);
        dailyCost.push_back(dayCost);
        dailySales.push_back(dayTotal);
        tempVec.clear();
        dayTotal = 0;
        dayCost = 0;
        iterate = 0;
    }
}

transaction::transaction(int year, int month, int day, double avg, double dev) {
    rng random;
    transTime = &testing;
    testing = random.newTime(year, month, day);
    itemCount = round(random.newNum('l', avg, dev,0));
    if(itemCount <= 0) {
        itemCount = 1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<itemCount; i++) {
        int select = random.newNum(0,libs::products.products.size());
        items.push_back(libs::products.products[select]);
        transTotal += items[i].returnPrice();
        transCost += items[i].returnCost();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are within a factor of two of your memory capacity, it might just be cheaper (your time isn't free) to buy another hunk of RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are running into memory issues is because as you add elements to the vector it eventually has to resize it's internal buffer. This entails allocating a new block of memory, copying the existing data to the new member and then deleting the old buffer.

Since you know the number of elements the vector will hold before hand you can call the vectors `reserve()` member function to allocate the memory ahead of time. This will eliminate the constant resizing that you are no doubt encountering now.

For instance in the constructor for `transaction` you would do the following before the loop that adds data to the vector.

```
items.reserve(itemCount);
```

In `store::populateTransactions()` you should calculate the total number of elements the vector will hold and call `tempVec.reserve()` in the same was described above. Also keep in mind that if you are using a local variable to populate the vector you will eventually need to copy it. This will cause the same issues as the destination vector will need to allocate memory before the contents can be copied (unless you use move semantics available in C++11). If the data needs to be returned to the calling function (as opposed to being a member variable of `store`) you should take it by reference as a parameter.

```
void store::populateTransactions(vector<transaction>& tempVec)
{
    //....
}
```

If it is not practical to determine the number of elements ahead of time you should consider using [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead. From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

> As opposed to std::vector, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays.
>
> The storage of a deque is automatically expanded and contracted as needed. Expansion of a deque is cheaper than the expansion of a std::vector because it does not involve copying of the existing elements to a new memory location.

In regard to the comment by [Rafael Baptista](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412808/rafael-baptista) about how the resize operation allocates memory the following example should give you a better idea of what it going on. The amount of memory listed is the amount required *during* the resize

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int>    data;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10000001; i++)
    {
        size_t oldCap = data.capacity();
        data.push_back(1);
        size_t newCap = data.capacity();
        if(oldCap != newCap)
        {
            std::cout
                << "resized capacity from "
                << oldCap
                << " to "
                << newCap
                << " requiring " << (oldCap + newCap) * sizeof(int)
                << " total bytes of memory"
                << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with VC++10 the following results are generated when adding 1,000,001 elements to a vector. These results are specific to VC++10 and can vary between implementations of `std::vector`.

> resized capacity from 0 to 1 requiring 4 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 1 to 2 requiring 12 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 2 to 3 requiring 20 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 3 to 4 requiring 28 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 4 to 6 requiring 40 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 6 to 9 requiring 60 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 9 to 13 requiring 88 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 13 to 19 requiring 128 total bytes of memory
>
> ...snip...
>
> resized capacity from 2362204 to 3543306 requiring 23622040 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 3543306 to 5314959 requiring 35433060 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 5314959 to 7972438 requiring 53149588 total bytes of memory
>   resized capacity from 7972438 to 11958657 requiring 79724380 total bytes of memory

Comment: Ok, I think i understand what you are saying, and it should be easy enough to implement.  I will be able to use it throughout my program as well.  As for the transactions, calculating the number of transactions ahead of time will be very difficult, but I could do just a high number and let it reallocate if it reaches it.  I will look at my short program and see what the average max is.  Thanks for the advice, hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Adalast If you can't determine the number of elements ahead of time switch to using `std::deque`. It allocates memory in chunks and you won't run into the reallocation problems you do with `std::vector` I've edited my answer to reflect this

Comment: I doubt this is the problem. The resize will happen very few times in practice. These implementations tend to grow the underlying buffer using a geometric progression e.g. resize the underlying buffer to 150% of its current size, or double each time. Clearing the vector won't delete the buffer. ( or at least it shouldn't in a sane implementation ) It just clears the count. So if you reuse the same vector object, you won't have any resizes after a few iterations.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista Given the amount of data the poster is processing to initially fill the vector it will eventually have to perform a resize. If the current block is 1gb in size and progression is 150% you will end up requiring 2.5gb of memory during the resize operation. This means even a sane implementation of vector is likely cause the symptoms described in the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of inserting elements into a vector and the resulting memory requirements for the resize operation.

Comment: I implemented reserve, and it has seemed to help considerably on the memory issues.  I am going to look at deque after this test is finished running and I can see how long it actually took to complete.  I am still running out of memory with reserve, but it has taken much longer.  I am also looking into purchasing more ram, the combination of the two should yield my desired results if I have estimated properly.

I will also give an update after I look at deque.

Answer (score 1):

This is fun! Some quick comments I can think of.

a. STL clear() does not always free the memory instantaneously. Instead you can use `std::vector<transaction>().swap(tmpVec);`.

b. If you are using a compiler which has C++11 vector::emplace_back then you should remove the push_back and use it. It should be a big boost both in memory and speed. With push_back you basically have two copies of the same data floating around and you are at the mercy of allocator to return it back to the OS.

c. Any reason you cannot flush dailyTransactions to disk every once in a while? You can always serialize the vector and write it out to disk, clear the memory and you should be good again.

d. As pointed by others, reserve should also help a lot.

Comment: reserve has helped quite a bit.  I am going to check into the swap to see how well it works.  Also, I am using Dev-C++ 5.4.2 with a C++11 compiler turned on, so I will definitely have to look at emplace_back.  

I have been considering how to do a disk cache for the daily transactions, but currently my disk space is limited as well.  Also, other than fstream, I don't really know any good ways to handle writing to/reading from disk.  any suggestions there?

Comment: a. You either need more RAM or more disk to accomplish this. So none of the optimizations will work unless you provide either one of them


b. I don't understand the 'disk cache for the dailyTransactions' you mention. I see its only used for writes here. So you can use flush() to keep syncing data to disk and keep clearing. Once this memory exhaustive part is done, you can read all data back from disk to RAM and speed up the process.

c. C style FILE* or C++ default API should be good. Any reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: I would probably go with my instructor for comp sci 1 was the worst teacher I have ever had and didn't go into any decent topics with any more depth than a puddle, so I am having to learn all of the concepts on my own as I stumble through them.  I have never even heard of .flush() and not sure what you mean by the C++ default API in this context.  I have seen FILE* and have used it in other areas of this program, just not sure how to utilize it for this context.  I am looking into maxing the ram on my computer, as well as freeing up some hard drive space.

Comment: flush force syncs data to disk so that the OS buffers holding the data are free'd up. By C++ default API I mean the fstream API. A good starting point would be http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream . You know what the size of a transaction object is, take a conservative guess and find how many elements you can hold in RAM in the vector. Once you have that many elements, serialize the vector and write it out to disk. Make sure to call flush. Empty all the vectors and start building it from where you left. One liner, (disk)file-backed-memory.